# pass text area value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a text area in my php page and I want to pass the value of this into php page when teaxt area is changing.

```
<textarea name=taskDescn id=taskDescn rows=25 onclick="updatetTaskDescription()" </textarea>

function updatetTaskDescription()
{
  $('#taskDescn').bind('input', function() {
    var taskDescription = $("#taskDescn").val();
    //alert('ok');
    //alert(taskDescription);
    $.post('../myfolder/edit.php', {taskDescription:taskDescription}, function (data) {
         alert(taskDescription);
    });
    });

}
```

in edit.php

```
$taskdescription=$_POST['taskDescription'];
```

my problem is I can not get value for $taskdescription in edit.php.please any body help me to solve this

Comment: Open the console, check the network tab, what is the status of the request?

Comment: Try using `$("#taskDescn").html();` instead of `$("#taskDescn").val();`. That solved it for me

Comment: I can not see any thing in console

Comment: Are you positive the post request is even being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the quotes were missing in your textarea attributes.

Try this:

```
<textarea name="taskDescn" id="taskDescn" rows="25" onclick="updatetTaskDescription()"> </textarea>
```

Comment: I can get text area value in jquery and I want to pass this into edit.php

Answer (score 0):

Seem like your HTML is invalid, you need to wrap the attribute value inside quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "` as well as you're missing `>` after specifying the attributes for your `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea name="taskDescn" id="taskDescn" rows="25" onclick="updatetTaskDescription()"> AASV</textarea>
```

Comment: I changed but still I can not get that value.

Comment: What is the result when you uncomment `alert(taskDescription);`?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. nothing happend after uncomment alerts

Comment: I means did you receive the correct `taskDescription` value when doing `alert`?

Comment: Also, are you sure `../myfolder/edit.php` is the correct path to `edit.php`?

Comment: yes i'm getting correct value in alert and path is also correct

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var_dump($_POST);` in your edit.php file.  Avoid using relative links for AJAX because sometimes you will run into security issues.

I'm not sure if the question's formatting is to blame, but it looks like your `<textarea>` tag is left unterminated. Also, as of jQuery 1.7 `.on()` is recommended over `.bind()` for [more efficient event handling](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) which applies especially to this case where you are making an AJAX call any time the input changes. Furthermore, I think your function only needs to be called a single time. The way it is coded now, every time you click on the textarea you will create a new event handler for the `input` event that executes your AJAX request every time the text inside the textarea changes. This could lead to multiple AJAX requests every time the text changes.

Comment: in my jquery var taskDescription = $("#taskDescn").val();and i'm sending taskDescription to my edit.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove onclick event from textarea. Try following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('input', '#taskDescn', function() {
        var taskDescription = $("#taskDescn").val();
        //alert('ok');
        //alert(taskDescription);
        $.post('../myfolder/edit.php', {taskDescription:taskDescription}, function (data) {
           alert(taskDescription);
        });
    });
});
```